# Google Play app reviews and specifications

Tags: android, google-play, review

I'm looking for some information on the details shown in an app's page on the Google Play.

1. User reviews

   - Does a user get a chance to rate the app after each version change?
   - Does the reviews has an expiration date?
   - Can spam reviews be removed from the total app score rating?
   - If a user rate the app after an update - does it replace his previous review?
   - Can I reset the app rating and delete all user reviews?
2. Installs number

   - Does the Google Play count downloads once per Google account?
   - If a user uninstalls and re-installs an app - does it gets counted again to the total installs number?
3. Can I change the app's name/publisher once it is published on Google Play?

Thanks for the help,

PB

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does a user get a chance to rate the app after each version change?

Users can update and change their ratings at any time, but they cannot have a unique rating for every version of your app. At any point of time, one user can only have one rating.

> Does the reviews has an expiration date?

No.

> Can spam reviews be removed from the total app score rating?

If enough users mark it as spam or flag the review, Google will remove it.

> If a user rate the app after an update - does it replace his previous review?

Yes

> Can I reset the app rating and delete all user reviews?

This is only possible if you unpublish the old app and publish it again under a new package name. You cannot delete the old reviews and recent your rating while using the same package name.

> Does the Google Play count downloads once per Google account?

I'm not sure about this, and can't find any documentation on it, but I think they count downloads once per account, not device, as one of my paid apps has been bought less times than its been installed.

> If a user uninstalls and re-installs an app - does it gets counted again to the total installs number?

It may show up in the total installs for a while, but Google Play adjusts these metrics, and it will remove the double count and count it only once when the adjustment happens.

> Can I change the app's name/publisher once it is published on Google Play?

Yes and yes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any Idea on your 1 Question on USER REVIEWS but I can answer you the next 2 Points.

For 2. Installs Number:

The below points are taken into consideration:

User statistics:

1. Total user installs - the total number of unique users that have
   ever installed this app. We only count one install regardless of how
   many different devices they installed it on. It includes the users
   who have later uninstalled the app.
2. Active user installs - the number of users who have the app
       currently installed on at least one of their devices.
3. Daily user installs - the number of unique users who installed this
       app for the the first time during that day.
4. Daily user uninstalls - the number of unique users who uninstalled
       the app from all devices during that day.

Device statistics:

1. Active device installs - the number of devices on which the
   application is currently installed - it excludes any devices where
   the application was uninstalled.
2. Daily device installs - the number of new devices on which the app
   was installed for the first time during that day.
3. Daily device uninstalls - the number of unique devices which
   uninstalled the app in the past day.
4. Daily device upgrades - the number of unique devices upgraded from
   an older version to the latest version of the app in the past day.

For 3rd Question:

You Can change any App's Info on your Developer Console except for the Package Name. But it takes some time to get Updated on Google Play Store.

Comment: Another thing you cannot change is the paid/free status of the app.

Comment: @Nagaraj436 actually it is possible to change the status of your app from paid to free, but once it is free you cannot make it paid again